# Node.js (Express) Form Clears on Submission

Tags: node.js, validation, express

I am working on a really basic registration form in Node.js (with Express), and I am trying to find the easiest way to provide basic form validation. I've gone with "Express-Validator", which seems to do a fine job. However, my goal is to simply show any validation messages that are required and to **leave the values entered by the user alone.**

It seems that the request information is not making it back into the res.render, which I guess makes sense. However, I've looked everywhere I can think of and I can't find any reference that discusses how to keep form fields populated after showing error messages.

Below is a small snippet describing my approach:

```
post: function(req, res){

            var userName = req.body.username;
            var password = req.body.password;

            //Validate input
            req.assert("username", 'Invalid email address.').isEmail();
            req.assert("password", 'Password cannot be empty.').notEmpty();
            req.assert("passwordConfirm", 'Passwords entered do not match!').equals(password);

            //Make sure we have no validation errors
            var pageErrors = req.validationErrors();
            if(!pageErrors)
            {
                userModel.CreateUser(userName, password, function(err){
                    if(err)
                    {
                        //there was a problem inserting new user... probably already exists
                        //will need to check the error to confirm
                        var dbErrorMessage = "Could not insert record into database!";
                        if(err.code === 11000)
                        {
                            //this is a duplicate entry
                            dbErrorMessage = "A user with that email address already exists!";
                        }

                        res.render('register.html', { pageErrors: [{msg: dbErrorMessage }]});
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        res.render('register.html', { successMessage: successMessage });
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                res.render('register.html', { pageErrors: pageErrors });
            }
```

Comment: This is what people mean when they say that "the web is stateless". You need to manually re-populate your values after each request.

Comment: Yeah, I realized it would require intervention from the server side to pass back the values, but I was hoping that express had something (or a middleware add-on) that might do this for us. I'll just go the AJAX form submission route. It'd make a better user experience anyway.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have to repopulate the form manually. If you get any page errors, you will pass back the form values to the view.

```
        if(!pageErrors)
        {
            // ...
        }
        else
        {
            res.render('register.html', { 
                pageErrors: pageErrors,
                userName: userName
            });
        }
```

And in your view, you would do a simple check to see if their are any errors and repopulate accordingly. You would have to keep track of what errors are produced for each form field.

```
<% if (userNameError) { %>
    <input type="text" name="userName" value="<%- userName %>" />
<% } else { %>
    <input type="text" name="userName" />
<% } %>
```

Another popular way is to send your form via ajax to to the server, and do all your validations. If there is an error, the entered form data remains and you would show the error, otherwise redirect after the successful login. Below is an example of how to submit a form with javascript.

```
$("#login-button").live("submit", function (e) {

    // this will prevent the form from being uploaded to the server the conventioanl way
    e.preventDefault();

    // the form data
    var data = $(this).serialize();

    // this logs the user in 
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: BASE_URL + '/login',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data, status) {
            // successful
        },

    });

    // superfluous fallback
    return false; 
});
```

Comment: +1. Depending on the complexity of the app, it may be relatively easy to submit the form via Ajax, and return the error messages via JSON (and update the page accordingly with JavaScript).

Comment: Thanks, I think that's just the way I'm going to have to go, then. I'll just do form submissions as AJAX calls and go from there. I thought it might be "easier" to do full posts back, but that was on the assumption that express could somehow help in passing back input values. I guess that's what I get for coming from .NET!

Answer (score 5):

There is an easy way is you are using

```
app.use(express.bodyParser()) and app.use(expressValidator());
```

You can use req.body

```
res.render('register.html', { 
         pageErrors: pageErrors,
         validated: req.body
   });
```

And I'm not sure which templating language you are using but you could do something like..

```
<input type="text" name="userName" value="<%= pageErrors.userName.value || validated.userName %>" />
```

This then gives back the good input if ok or the bad input if it needs correcting.

Comment: Thank you, I think this is actually the correct way to use the "pageErrors" that expressValidator generates. I should do a combination of AJAX validation and then use this as the fallback in case of JavaScript being disabled.

Answer (score 3):

You can get this done using `connect-flash`

Below are the code snippets in different files in order to get the values entered by the user back in form when validations fail while doing signup with passport.

Run this below command to add new package into package.json

```
npm install connect-flash --save
```

**app.js**

```
var flash = require('connect-flash');

app.use(flash()); // add this above passport initialize
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

**config/passport.js** (Please focus on form data loading into flash)

```
passport.use('local.signup', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true
}, function (req, email, password, done) {
    req.checkBody('first_name', 'Firstname is missing').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('last_name', 'Lastname is missing').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email', 'Invalid email').notEmpty().isEmail();
    req.checkBody('password', 'Password is too short. Minimum size is 6.').notEmpty().isLength({min:6});
    req.checkBody('confirm_password', 'Password and confirm password didn\'t not match').equals(req.body.password);
    var errors = req.validationErrors();
    if (errors) {
            var messages = [];
            errors.forEach(function(error) {
                 messages.push(error.msg);
            });
            req.flash('formdata', req.body); // load form data into flash
            return done(null, false, req.flash('error', messages));
    }
    User.findOne({'email': email}, function (err, user) {
            if (err) {
                    req.flash('formdata', req.body); // load form data into flash
                    return done(err);
            }
            if (user) {
                    req.flash('formdata', req.body); // load form data into flash
                    return done(null, false, {message: 'Email is already in use.'});
            }
            var newUser = new User();
            newUser.first_name = req.body.first_name;
            newUser.last_name = req.body.last_name;
            newUser.email = email;
            newUser.password = newUser.encryptPassword(password);
            newUser.save(function(err, result) {
                 if (err) {
                         return done(err);
                 }
                 return done(null, newUser);
            });
    });
}));
```

**routes/index.js** (Please focus on form data in flash loaded back into a variable)

```
    router.get('/signup', function (req, res, next) {
    var messages = req.flash('error');
    var formdata = req.flash('formdata'); // Get formdata back into a variable   
    res.render('user/signup', {csrfToken: req.csrfToken(),
        messages: messages, // pass it here to access in view file
        hasErrors: messages.length > 0,
        formData: formdata[0]
    });
});

router.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local.signup', {
        badRequestMessage: 'Please fill the form with all details',
        failureRedirect: '/user/signup',
        failureFlash: true
    }), function (req, res, next) {
        if (req.session.oldUrl) {
            var oldUrl = req.session.oldUrl;
            req.session.oldUrl = null;
            res.redirect(oldUrl);
        } else {
            res.redirect('/user/profile');
        }
});
```

**views/signup.hbs** (Please focus on values in input elements)

```
<form class="wow fadeInUp animated" data-wow-delay=".7s" action="/user/signup" method="post" >
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="first_name" value="{{ formData.first_name }}">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="last_name" value="{{ formData.last_name }}">
    <input type="text" class="email" placeholder="Email Address" name="email" value="{{ formData.email }}">
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" class="lock" placeholder="Password">
    <input type="password" name="confirm_password" value="" class="lock" placeholder="Confirm Password">
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{ csrfToken }}">
    <input type="submit" name="Register" value="Register"></form>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi. why this works for you but not for me? i use this code `const user = req.flash('user')[0] ? req.flash('user')[0] : { email: '', fullname: '', phone: '' };`  but still do not work. when i log req.flash('user') it  shows me something like this `[{ email: 'ada@asd.com', fullname: 'asdasd', phone: '1321465' }]`

Answer (score 0):

set a variable for all the input, for example

```
var inputData = {
  firstname : req.body.firstname,
  lastname : req.body.lastname,
  email : req.body.email,
  username : req.body.username,
  password : req.body.password,
  password_confirmation : req.body.password_confirmation,
  agreetoterms: req.body.agreetoterms
}
```

and then pass that variable to the view

```
res.render('register.html', { pageErrors: [{msg: dbErrorMessage }], inputData: inputData });
```

then in your view

```
value="<%= inputData.userName %>"
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jade and form Validator from npm , the best part is that you can an if statement in jade and then you simply check if error then with res.render we send the objects also . See This

```
if(errors){
    res.render('register',{
        errors : errors,
        name : name,
        email : email,
        username : username,
        password : password,
        password2 : password2
    });
```

And in jade you do this

```
input.form-control(name='name',type='text',placeholder='Enter Name',value = (errors ? '#{name}':''))
```

so if there is errors value will set to variable in name which will rendered when we send back

I think you can also be done in Angular2/Angular.js

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a simple way to achieve this. Do following in controller:

```
else{
    res.render('register.html', { pageErrors: pageErrors, inputData: req.body});
}
```

Now, in your ejs (or do it according to your view engine) file do following:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<% if(typeof pageErrors !== "undefined"){ %> <%- inputData.name %> <% } %>" class="form-control">
```

Answer (score -1):

check http://www.quietless.com/kitchen/building-a-login-system-in-node-js-and-mongodb/

on register.html make this

```
    var data = {};
        data.user = $('#user-input').val();
        data.email = $('#email-input').val();
        data.pass = $('#pass-input').val();
    $.ajax({ url: '/signup'
           , type: 'POST'
           , data: JSON.stringify(data)
           , contentType: 'application/json'
           , dataType: 'html'
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            if (data == 'ok') {
                $('#content').html('You are registered!');
            }
            else $('#account-form-container').append('<br>error:' + data);
        });
```

there might be error like: CANNOT POST /

in this case the author of tutorial on link above uses lib $.ajaxForm

you can also use https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable

or $('#myform').submit() replace to $('#submit-a-link').click()