# Show User the error message when problem when logging in

Tags: node.js, angularjs, html, express, passport.js

I have just started working on an already existing Web application project. Right now when the user tries logging in with incorrect credentials , the page is getting redirected to 'relogin' page. Where the Message "Please enter valid credentials" is hardcoded in the HTML to show a "error message". I have been asked to add another functionality to the Application. I want to show the user the message which server returns.

For Example :-
If server response is

```
    { result : "false" , message : " Invalid email "  }
```

i want to show "Please enter Valid email" to the user.

If server response is

```
    { result : "false" ,message : " Invalid password "  }
```

i want to show "Please enter Correct Password" to the user.

,but because of the present code  i am not able to do that.

Please help me with this task.

Thanks in advance.

I am attaching my app.js , passport.js , authenticate.js code. please inform if you need any more details.

--app.js--

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var initPassport = require('./passport');

initPassport(passport);

var routes = require('./routes/routes');
var authenticate = require('./routes/authenticate')(passport);

app.use('/',routes);
app.use('/auth',authenticate);
```

'''

--authenticate.js--

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var path = require('path');

module.exports = function(passport) {

router.get('/logout', function(req, res){
req.logout();
res.redirect('/');
});

router.post('/login',passport.authenticate('login',{
successRedirect: '/',
failureRedirect: '/relogin',
}));

return router;
};
```

'''

--passport.js--

```
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var pg = require('pg');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;

var client = new Client();

module.exports = function(passport){

passport.use('login', new LocalStrategy({
passReqToCallback : true
},
function(req, username, password, done) {
var client = new Client();

client.get(serverHost+serverRoot+"/validateuser?username="+username+"&                    password="+password, function (data, response) {
// parsed response body as js object 
// raw response 
console.log("response from server ", data);
if(data.result == "true")
    return done(null, username); 
else
  return done(null ,false );
});
}));

}
```

'''
**EDIT 1 :-**

There is no angular code for logging in.
All the procedure happens in html only.
I am attaching the HTML code. Thanks
HTML code   :-

```
<body>

<div class="col-md-6 offset-3">

<form action="/auth/login" method="post"  >

<div class="form-group mb-4 mt-4"><input id="email" class="form-control
    form-control-rounded" type="text" name = "username"
placeholder="Username"   ></div>

<div class="form-group mb-4 mt-4"><input id="password" class="form-control
    form-control-rounded" type="password" name="password"
  placeholder="Password"></div>

<button type = "submit" value = "Login"  class="btn btn-rounded btn-primary btn-block mt-2">Sign In</button>

</form>
</div>


</body>
```

Comment: Please share your client side (angular) code where you are trying to implement this change. What did you try & what is the exact problem you are facing on the client side implementation?

Comment: hi @AbhasTandon , thanks for taking a look at my problem. Please See my EDIT 1.

Comment: I don't see any hardcoded error message in your `HTML` code. Where is the error coming from in the view?

Comment: its the same html code , with a span tag at the top saying <strong>Please Enter Valid Credentials!</strong>  . I wrote the code to redirect to this hardcoded html if failure in log in. Basically if '/relogin' is requested the hardcoded page will get rendered.

Comment: a better approach would be to redirect them to the same login page and pass it correct data using `red.render` then use that data in your html template engine. Checkout https://expressjs.com/en/api.html

Comment: thanks for pointing out a method , but in order to send the data , i have to get the data till my res.render code.But i am not able to send the extra data in passport.js file itself. Even if send the data by some method how should i change my authenticate.js ? because now the only thing its doing is just redirecting to some url and not passing any extra data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39223723/send-data-back-with-the-passport-js-failureredirect-method

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out , i did some more research  and it got my problem solved . If you want post it as an answer , i will mark as correct one. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `res.render` function to send data to your view. Documentation for the same is available at:
https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render

Regarding the specific issue related to validation via passport.js have a look at:
[Send data back with the Passport js failureRedirect method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39223723/send-data-back-with-the-passport-js-failureredirect-method)